# Cant get redux state from component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, frontend

Simple counter app.State is changing as expected when button clicked ,which I can track in redux dev tools.However I cant access the  count redux state from the counter component.What am I doing wrong exactly?

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import  addone from '../actions/addone';



const Counter = ({addone,count}) => {
    
    console.log(count);
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Value:{count}</h1>
            <button type="button" onClick={()=>addone()}>Add 1</button>

        </div>
    )
}


const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    count:state.count
  });

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { addone })(Counter);
```

output nothing is shown after value.

[image]

Comment: this looks ok to me at first glance. What does addone() and the reducer look like?

Answer (score -1):

you need to use `useSelector` hook in functional components i edited your code:

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import { useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import  addone from '../actions/addone';

const Counter = () => {
    const count = useSelector((state) => state.count);
    console.log(count);
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Value:{count}</h1>
            <button type="button" onClick={()=>addone()}>Add 1</button>

        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: They are using the `connect` function so you don't need to use the `useSelector` hook.